# Djando update model data

Tags: python, django

I want to update model's data. I am using Django Rest Framework.I am making a system saved user data to model.I wrote in views.py

```
class InfoViews(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    queryset = Info.objects.all()
    serializer_class = InfoSerializer
    lookup_field = 'id'

    def update(self,request, *args, **kwargs):
        data = request.data
        info_serializers = InfoSerializer(data = data)
        if info_serializers.is_valid(raise_exception=True):
            info_serializers.save()
            return JsonResponse(info_serializers.data)
```

in serializers.py

```
class InfoSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    created_time = serializers.DateTimeField(required=False)

    class Meta:
        model = Info
        fields = '__all__'
```

in models.py

```
class Info(models.Model):
    username = custom_fields.NotEmptyCharField(max_length=100, unique=True)
    email = models.EmailField()
    password = custom_fields.NotEmptyCharField(max_length=100)

    class Meta:
        db_table = 'info'
```

When I run this codes,always when i update a record,new record is made.Is it cause save() of info_serializers.save()? What is wrong in my codes?How should I fix this?

Comment: Shouldn't this info_serializers = InfoSerializer(data = data)  be info_serializers = InfoSerializer.filter(data = data).all() ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

simply remove the `info_serializers.save()` will solve your problem.
I would like to add some suggestion for you,
You don't need to override the `update()` because `ModelViewSet` class doing all that stuff for you by default, see [this official DRF doc](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/viewsets/#modelviewset)

Use just class definition for the `CRUD` application along with [default router](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/routers/#defaultrouter) as below

```
class InfoViews(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    queryset = Info.objects.all()
    serializer_class = InfoSerializer
    lookup_field = 'id'
```

Comment: thank you for your answer.I removed info_serializers.save() ,but "user info with this username already exists." error happens.I think program tried to create a new record.

Comment: Maybe you had tried to update an instance with a value which is already in DB

Comment: You don't have to override methods unless you really need to (It's just a suggestion)